# zsh git COMMAND autocomplete and filename autocomplete together?

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh

**NOTE: I know there are many questions about autocomplete, but I am specifically asking a question about autocompletion of the git command, not regular autocomplete for listing files in a directory.**

I am running Mac Catalina and have finally decided to hop on the zsh train. I wanted to get git command auto complete working (i.e. I type `git a` and hit tab and options for `add`,  `apply`,  etc come up).

I performed the recommended addition of `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` to my ~/.zshrc file and voilà I had git command completion. Yay!

However, once I get to the `git add` point and try to tab complete to get the names of the files in the directory, I get nothing. Regular tab completion for `ls`, `cp`, etc work fine, but not for `git` after the addition of a command.

Is there a way to fix this problem so that I can get both the command autocomplete AND the file autocomplete working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working. Have you definitely got modified or untracked files in your current directory? I'd recommend the following configuration style so that it will tell you:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:warnings' format 'No matches for: %d'
```

Does completion after something else like `git mv` work?

Comment: You are entirely correct. I was in a directory that didn't have modified files so of course it wouldn't have shown anything. And your zstyle configuration style works perfectly. Thanks!